# How would I group columns together but filter a specific group that is created using the group_by function

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr, rstudio

```
library(nycflights13)

data <- flights 
flights %>% group_by(carrier)
```

I'm using the nycflights13 data as an example, I'm trying to figure out how to us the group_by function, group the carriers together and filter the carrier US to be > 1 .

Comment: The condition is not clear  `> 1` in which column?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a misunderstanding of how group_by operates. From ?group_by:

```
> ?group_by
Most data operations are done on groups defined by variables. group_by() takes 
an existing tbl and converts it into a grouped tbl where operations are 
performed "by group" [...] grouping doesn't change how the data looks [...]
It changes how it acts with the other dplyr verbs.
```

From what I can gather, you looking for a count of the same flights that are > 1 for carrier US. Group_by alone may not be the best option. Group_by is useful when applying an operation at the group level, such as finding mean delay time:

```
> flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>% na.omit(.) %>%  
  summarise(mean = mean(dep_delay))
 # A tibble: 16 x 2
 carrier  mean
 <chr>   <dbl>
 1 9E      16.4 
 2 AA      8.57
 3 AS      5.83
....
```

However, group_by won't alter or aggregate your data by itself.

```
> flights
# A tibble: 336,776 x 20
year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay
  <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>
1  2013   1    1        517            515      2.00
2  2013   1    1        533            529      4.00

flights %>% group_by(carrier)
A tibble: 336,776 x 20 ...
```

Notice no aggregation was preformed and the tibble contains that same number of observations. As others have implied in the comments, you may need to decide on what features you want to aggregate by and look at other aggregation functions to help. Below is an example that uses the "table" functions to produce a frequency table by "dest" and "origin" for carrier "US." Notice group_by was not used.

```
> flights %>% select(dest,carrier,origin) %>% filter(carrier == "US") %>% 
  table(.) %>% as_tibble(.) %>% filter(n > 1)

 # A tibble: 9 x 4
 dest  carrier origin     n
 <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <int>
1 CLT   US      EWR     3232
2 PHX   US      EWR     1172
```